# uncheck radiobutton/radiogroup on Button click - Android

Tags: android, radio-button, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I am using radiobuttons in my radiogroup and each radiogroup is generated dynamically. I want all radiogroup unchecked in more specific I want all radiobuttons in radiogroup should be unchecked when user click on **clear button**. **I using radiogroup in my listview and generating each listview using a custom adapter.**

Here is my code:

**Mainactivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView simpleListView;
private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
private String[] questions;
private Button submit, clear;
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
FileOutputStream fstream;
private boolean forceClear;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
    simpleListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
    View Listview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_items,null);
    RadioButton rb_yes = Listview.findViewById(R.id.yes);
    RadioButton rb_no =  Listview.findViewById(R.id.no);
    final RadioGroup radioGroup= Listview.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

    View footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer,null);
    clear= (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.clear);
    submit = (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.submit1);
    simpleListView.addFooterView(footerView);
    View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    simpleListView.addHeaderView(headerView);
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext() , questions);
    simpleListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             radioGroup.check(-1);
            radioGroup.clearCheck();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "please answer" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
        radioButton.setChecked(false);
    }
}});


    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String message = "";
            boolean found_unanswered = false;
            if(customAdapter != null){
                for(int i = 0 ; i<customAdapter.getSelectedAnswers().size() ; i++){
                    if(customAdapter.getSelectedAnswers().get(i).equals("3")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "please answer" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        found_unanswered = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    message = message + "\n" + (i + 1) + " " + customAdapter.getSelectedAnswers().get(i);
                }
            }

            if(!found_unanswered){
                try {
                    fstream = openFileOutput("user_answer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fstream.write(message.getBytes());
                    fstream.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,message , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent inent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(inent);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

public void clearButtonClicked (View view){
    View Listview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_items,null);
    RadioGroup radioGroup= Listview.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

    radioGroup.clearCheck();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  int id = item.getItemId();



    if (id == R.id.about) {
        Intent inent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, devicedetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(inent);
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.admin) {
        Intent inent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, adminactivity.class);
        startActivity(inent);

        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.SerialPort) {
        Intent inent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
        startActivity(inent);

        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.customservice) {
        Intent inent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, testactivity_main.class);
        startActivity(inent);
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.exit) {
        ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(MainActivity.this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Custom Adapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
String[] questionsList;
LayoutInflater inflter;
public ArrayList<String> selectedAnswers;

public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] questionsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.questionsList = questionsList;
    selectedAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < questionsList.length; i++) {
        selectedAnswers.add("3");
    }
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return questionsList.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return questionsList[i];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return questionsList.length;

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View view = convertView;


    if (convertView == null) {
        if (inflter != null) {
            view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);

        }
    }


    TextView question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.question);
    question.setText(questionsList[i]);

    // initialize/ restore UI Radio Button State
    final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    final RadioButton rb_yes = (RadioButton) rg.findViewById(R.id.yes);
    final RadioButton rb_no = (RadioButton) rg.findViewById(R.id.no);
    if(selectedAnswers.get(i).equals("1")){
        rg.check(R.id.yes);
        rb_yes.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        rb_no.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }else if(selectedAnswers.get(i).equals("2")){
        rg.check(R.id.no);
        rb_yes.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        rb_no.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,165,0));
    }else{
        // no answer.
        rb_yes.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        rb_no.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }

    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton rb_yes = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(R.id.yes);
            RadioButton rb_no = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(R.id.no);
            switch (checkedId){
                case R.id.yes:
                    rb_yes.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    rb_no.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    selectedAnswers.set(i, "1");
                    break;
                case R.id.no:
                    rb_yes.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    rb_no.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,165,0));
                    selectedAnswers.set(i, "2");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });


    return view;
}

public List<String> getSelectedAnswers(){
    return selectedAnswers;
}
```

**Footer.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="5dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="30sp"
   />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/clear"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:text="Clear"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    />
```

**Listitem.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/White">
<!-- TextView for displaying question-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    />
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main">
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@color/Black"
            android:button="@null"
            android:paddingHorizontal="30dp"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:text="YES"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="50dp" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@color/Black"
            android:button="@null"
            android:paddingHorizontal="30dp"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:text="NO"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="50dp" />
    </RadioGroup>
</FrameLayout>
```

I don't know where I am going wrong.

```
   clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this..

```
RadioGroup radiogrp = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogrp);
```

Inside onclick

```
radiogrp.clearCheck();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for a simple task like this does not needs a full JavaScript library like jQuery.

```js
document.getElementById("main2").addEventListener("click", function()
{
    document.getElementById("subCheckButtons").style.opacity = 1;
}, false);
document.getElementById("main1").addEventListener("click", function()
{
    document.getElementById("subCheckButtons").style.opacity = 0;
    document.getElementById("sub1").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("sub2").checked = false;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="main1" name="main" />
<input type="radio" id="main2" name="main" />
<div id="subCheckButtons" style="opacity:0;">
    <input type="radio" id="sub1" name="sub" class="subCheck" />
    <input type="radio" id="sub2" name="sub" class="subCheck" />
</div>
```