# android clear radiogroup onclick button(clear)

Tags: android, listview, android-view, android-adapterview, android-radiogroup

How to uncheck all the radiobuttons in radiogroup onclick of a button. What are the possible codes. Tried radiogroup.clearcheck() - Not working. 
My radiogroup is in listview.
calling button and listview from two different layout.

On button(clear) click radiobutton should be unchecked

To view code please follow the post [repeated post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236639/uncheck-radiobutton-radiogroup-on-button-click-android)
Thank in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uncheck radiobutton/radiogroup on Button click - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236639/uncheck-radiobutton-radiogroup-on-button-click-android)

Comment: @GáborBakos yes, still looking for the solution. Tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CustomAdapter constructor from:

```
public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] questionsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.questionsList = questionsList;
    selectedAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < questionsList.length; i++) {
        selectedAnswers.add("3");
    }
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}
```

To:

```
public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] questionsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.questionsList = questionsList;
    resetAnswers();
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}

public void resetAnswers(){
    selectedAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < questionsList.length; i++) {
        selectedAnswers.add("3");
    }
}
```

And inside OnClick() for **Clear** Button:

```
customAdapter.resetAnswers();
customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you so so much. Solved my issue finally. :) -) legend.  Dam! the solution was so easy :). That is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To Clear all the RadioButtons in ListView, In  your Adapter Class ,

```
RadioButton rb;

rb.setChecked(false);
```

Pass Any Default Value for selected Answer .
Say selectedAnser = 0;

in your  Adapter ,

```
if(selectedAnswer.equals("0"))
{
//make all your radiobutton to checked false
radioButton.setChecked(false);
}
```

In your Activity , while making a clear button click,

```
 mClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

              for(int i=0;i<yourDatalist.size();i++)
                  {

                    yourDatalist.get(i).setSelectedAnswer = "0";
                  } 
               //make adapter notify  here
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: i have used this type of logics in my projects. Check your Code  thouroghly. u have to manually implement this logic in your activity

Comment: what goes under yourdatalist

Comment: you have to  pass a default  or zero value to the datalist you have made  in your activity and check the  value for zero in your adapter. if the value comes to zero , asuume the user presses the clear button and make all the radiobutton unchecked.

Comment: shiv snape thank you so much for your time. issue solved

Comment: Always Welcome @contact dummy.  Please Upvote my answer , if it is helpul to you.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 radioGroup.clearCheck();
```

or

```
radioGroup.check(-1);
```

or

```
             for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                            radioButton.setChecked(false);
                        }
```

Comment: tried all the solution. can you check my code and tell me where I am going wrong. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236639/uncheck-radiobutton-radiogroup-on-button-click-android)

Answer (score 0):

> use this example

radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioGroup.clearCheck();

```
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            if (null != rb && checkedId > -1) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}

public void onClear(View v) {
    /* Clears all selected radio buttons to default */
    radioGroup.clearCheck();
}
```

Comment: no luck.  onclick button crash. error:07-11 06:01:26.254 10488-10488/com.solution.tracking.forklift E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)